# what is n , how function is defined in script for the Javascript Slider Image

Tags: javascript, slider

I have some problem in the script -

Html -

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">jjjj</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Script -

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Question

1. If showSlides in  showSlides(slideIndex) is a function where slide Index is passed as a parimeter
2. What is n here , if it is a perimeter , why it's data type is not defined

   function plusSlides(n) {
         showSlides(slideIndex += n);
       }
3. If showSlides is a function then how it is defined under function plusSlides() function
4. What is n in the Script

Comment: In JavaScript you don't have to define data types, JS is what's called a dynamically typed language

Comment: `showSlides` is not defined in `plusSlides`, it's called there

Comment: What is `n`? The value that is passed in???

Answer (score 0):

`n` gets propagated as `1` here. When we call `showSlides(slideIndex)` we are really doing `showSlides(1)`. Since the only parameter of `showSlides` is `n`, then we're setting `n=1` in the scope of that specific function call.

`showSlides` is indeed a function, and all that `plusSlides(n)` does is call `showSlides` with a new parameter.

Comment: But why n type is not defined before it is used as a parameter into the function

Comment: As someone said earlier, in JS you don't need to define types because it is a dynamically typed language.